# How to detect Linux machine power off state using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the code I got from this website to detect resume,

```
import dbus      # for dbus communication (obviously)
import gobject   # main loop
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop # 
integration into the main loop
def handle_resume_callback():
    print "System just resumed from hibernate or suspend"

DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True) # integrate into main loob
bus = dbus.SystemBus()             # connect to dbus system wide
bus.add_signal_receiver(           # defince the signal to listen to
    handle_resume_callback,            # name of callback 
function
    'Resuming',                        # singal name
    'org.freedesktop.UPower',          # interface
    'org.freedesktop.UPower'           # bus name
)

loop = gobject.MainLoop()          # define mainloop
loop.run()                         # run main loop
```

Can any one please help me, what is the signal name to detect power off condition.

Comment: You need to catch SIGTERM. That is a signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to catch SIGTERM, SIGINT and SIGKILL signals.

```
import signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigterm_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGKILL, sigterm_handler)
```

You need SIGTERM for the power off. Mind though: pressing the buttons means the system will start a shutdown, so there is a limited amount of time before anything you want to do needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there any alternative to handle Linux sleep(suspend) and resume without using dbus and gobject.

Comment: I doubt any other way would be easier. There will be a systemd service for each of these, You can add a hook to those.

Comment: Can you please suggest any link or example

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124212/writing-a-systemd-service-to-be-executed-at-resume  has a couple of methods

Comment: According to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64282634/oserror-when-setting-sigkill-handler-in-mac-os-and-python , you cannot handle SIGKILL the same way as SIGTERM/SIGINT. How do you make it work?